# odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source

Tags: php, odbc, teradata, unixodbc

I want to create connection with `teradata` DB form `php`. My code is hosted on  `Ubuntu` server but the below error occurred.

> "odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name
>   not found, and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in
>   SQLConnect in /path".

while it is working properly from local host.

php code is:

```
$sDriver = 'Teradata';
$sDBCName = 'ip';
$sDatabase = 'dbname';
$sDSN = "Driver={$sDriver};DBCName={$sDBCName};Database={$sDatabase};";
$connection = odbc_connect($sDSN, "username", "password");
```

but there is nothing wrong in the code bcoz it is working on local host.

Comment: The error suggests that no associated drivers are installed on server.

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered from the same problem before. I somehow manage to fix it using this code:

```
$database = 'db';
$user = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$hostname = 'ip';
$port = portNo;
$db = odbc_connect("Driver={Your-Driver};HOSTNAME=$hostname;
                    Database=$database;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;", $user, $password);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This code is working fine on local host but when i try to run it from server it's create problem, can you plz confirm what configuration needed on server(ubuntu seerver)?

Comment: @NaveedUlIslam what was the error that you are currently expriencing?

Comment: this error:  odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in /path

Comment: Maybe its in your server configuration. It says in your error that there is not default driver specified.

Comment: Yes @miggy now what should be need on server to resolve this issue any idea?

Comment: @NaveedUlIslam maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237678/how-to-fix-the-unixodbcdriver-managerdata-source-name-not-found-and-no-defa

Comment: Your server needs to have the same ODBC source specified as does your local machine.

Comment: @access_granted, what configuration i need on server for resolving this issue?

Comment: You need an ODBC driver, and the same DNS name as the one you have on the client. Then the same code should work on both nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install both PHP ODBC extension and Microsoft's ODBC drivers for SQL server.

## Install PHP ODBC Extension

```sh
sudo apt-get install php7.2-odbc

# Note that on Ubuntu 16.04 and earlier you'll need to register this PPA first.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

## Install the Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Import GPG keys:

`bash curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

Register the Microsoft Ubuntu repository:

```sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list

# Note replace 16.04 in package URL aboive with your Ubuntu version. i.e. 14.04, 18.04, etc.
```

Download the drivers for your version of Ubuntu:

`bash sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17`

Install optional bcp and sqlcmd tools:

`bash sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tool`

## Connect from your PHP application

```php
<?php
$dsn = 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=server.domain;Database=database_name';
$username = 'your_username';
$password = 'your_password';
if($connection = odbc_connect($dsn, $username, $password, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC)) {
    echo "Connected to the datasource.";
} else {
    echo "Could not connect to the datasource.";
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: It is also valid for UBUNTU 18 LTS and 20 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

use this guide:
https://programadoresfv.blogspot.com/2014/08/despues-de-gastarme-todo-un-dia.html.
The configuration of the /etc/apache2/envvars file, is very important for Apache to recognize the name of the connections.
In this case add:

```
export ODBCINI=/opt/informix/etc/odbc.ini
export ODBCININST=/opt/informix/etc/odbcinst.ini
export INFORMIXDIR=/opt/informix
export INFORMIXSQLHOSTS=/opt/informix/etc/sqlhosts
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$INFORMIXDIR/lib:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/cli:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/tools
```